# AWK - Working with two files

Tags: awk

I have these two csv files:

File A:

```
veículo;carro;sust
automóvel;carro;sust
viatura;carro;sust
breve;rápido;adj
excepcional;excelente;adj
maravilhoso;excelente;adj
amistoso;simpático;adj
amigável;simpático;adj
...
```

File B:

```
"A001","carro","sust","excelente","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
...
```

In the file A, $1(word) is synonym for $2(word) and $3(word) the part of speech.

In the lines of the file B we can skip $1,the remaining columns are words and their part of speech.

What I need to to do is to look line by line each pair (word-pos) in the file A  and generate a line for each synonym. It is difficult to explain.

Desired Output:

```
"A001","carro","sust","excelente","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","viatura","sust","excelente","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","veículo","sust","excelente","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","automóvel","sust","excelente","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","carro","sust","excepcional","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","viatura","sust","excepcional","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","veículo","sust","excepcional","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","automóvel","sust","excepcional","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","carro","sust","maravilhoso","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","viatura","sust","maravilhoso","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","veículo","sust","maravilhoso","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","automóvel","sust","maravilhoso","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
```

Done:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="[,;]";
    OFS=";";
}
FNR==NR{
    sinonim[$1","$2","$3]++;
    next;
}
{

    s1=split($0,AX,"\n");
    for (i=1;i<=s1;i++)
    {
        s2=split(AX[i],BX,",");
        for (j=2;j<=NF;j+=2)
        {
            lineX=BX[j]","BX[j+1];
            gsub(/\"/,"",lineX);
            for (item in sinonim)
            {
                s3=split(item,CX,",");
                lineS=CX[2]","CX[3];
                if (lineX == lineS)
                {
                    BX[j]=CX[1];
                    lineD=""
                    for (t=1;t<=s2;t++)
                    {
                        lineD=lineD BX[t]",";
                    }
                    lineF=lineF lineD"\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print lineF

}
```

Comment: why in output the first 4 lines are duplicated 3 times? From your FileB, only first 4 lines should be outputted right?

Comment: @Kent, it looks like there are four choices for "carro" --- "carro" itself, and the three synonyms (veículo, automóvel, viatura). Similarly there are three choices for "excelente" (itself and two synonyms). "ocorrer" and "bom" have no synonyms, so only one choice for those. The 12 lines in the output are the 4 x 3 x 1 x 1 combinations of all the words in the file B record and their synonyms.

Comment: In the output, in each line the second instance of "sust" should be "adj", no?

Comment: @jas That's right! You've explained better than I do

Comment: I think AWK is a good tool, but when you write more than 3 line of AWK, you probably choose the wrong  tool

Comment: you need to use `awk` exclusively?

Comment: @ej_f It is not strictly necessary, but I prefer it. What do you propose?

Comment: @Firefly maybe modifying your input files and using other command line tools

Comment: @Troncador not at all, you have been seriously mis-informed. awk is the ideal tool for any text manipulation job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN   { FS=";" }
NR==FNR { synonyms[$2,$3][$2]; synonyms[$2,$3][$1]; next }
FNR==1  { FS=OFS="\",\""; $0=$0 }
{
    gsub(/^"|"$/,"")
    for (i=2;i<NF;i+=2) {
        if ( ($i,$(i+1)) in synonyms) {
            for (synonym in synonyms[$i,$(i+1)]) {
                $i = synonym
                for (j=2;j<NF;j+=2) {
                    if ( ($j,$(j+1)) in synonyms) {
                        for (synonym in synonyms[$j,$(j+1)]) {
                            orig = $0
                            $j = synonym
                            if (!seen[$0]++) {
                                print "\"" $0 "\""
                            }
                            $0 = orig
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk fileA fileB
"A001","carro","sust","excelente","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","veículo","sust","excelente","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","automóvel","sust","excelente","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","viatura","sust","excelente","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","carro","sust","maravilhoso","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","carro","sust","excepcional","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","veículo","sust","maravilhoso","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","veículo","sust","excepcional","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","automóvel","sust","maravilhoso","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","automóvel","sust","excepcional","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","viatura","sust","maravilhoso","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
"A001","viatura","sust","excepcional","adj","ocorrer","adv","bom","adj"
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-dimensional arrays, with other awks it's a simple tweak to use `synonyms[$2,$3] = synonyms[$2,$3] " " $2` etc. or similar and then `split()` later instead of `synonyms[$2,$3][$2]` and `in`.

Comment: Could you explain what value returns ($i,$(i+1)) ?. Because it is not the same as if I do this, right? `for (i=2;i<NF;i+=2) line=$i $(i+1); if (line in synonyms)`

Comment: Context matters. The context I assume you're referring to in my script is array indices and so `($i,$(i+1)) in array`=`($i SUBSEP $(i+1)) in array`, just like `array[$i,$(i+1)]`=`array[$i SUBSEP $(i+1)]`, but in a different context for printing output it'd be `print ($i,$(i+1))` = `print ($i OFS $(i+1))` while in yet another context for variable assignment `var=($i,$(i+1))`=`a syntax error`.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN { FS="[,;]"; OFS="," }
NR == FNR { key = "\"" $2 "\""; synonym[key] = synonym[key] "," $1; next }
{
    print;
    if ($2 in synonym) {
        count = split(substr(synonym[$2], 2), choices)
        for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            $2 = "\"" choices[i] "\""
            print
        }
    }
}
```